# which performance for multiple loop sql select

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a list of accounts, in which I loop and search one by one:

```
for (Account acc: accs) {
   // select table where accid, accname, status, etc... match per sql request
}
```

I am thinking of using sql IN:

```
for (Account acc: accs) {
   // join all accid, accname, status, etc in string seperate by comma,
   // example: 1,2,3,4 for accname, 'alvin', 'john' for accname
}
// then select using IN
// example: SELECT * FROM Tx WHERE acccId IN (1,2,3,4) AND accName IN ('alvin', 'john)
```

Do you think using IN performance will be better for more then 100 accId or name?

> I see the method 1 is more flexible because the condition can be
> complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running one query with `IN` will be much, much faster than running 100 separate queries.

There is overhead to running separate queries -- just turning the query into an execution plan and passing the database out.  In general, it is better to do more in the database and less in the application.